# Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook.Contracts, Version=5.0.40.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-c#-sdk, nuget

I'm currently trying to get the latest facebook sdk for my website to work. I'm using NuGet to download and install this onto my website.

In the last few weeks I built a simple site using this sdk and was able to get it to work just fine. Now I'm trying to add this into a new project and I'm getting this error on compile.

My NuGet is the latest version (I updated it today) and when I create a blank, new project, just now it worked fine when I added in the facebook sdk.

My website is in a solution with another project, if that makes any difference. The other issue I noticed is that when I open up the properties page in my website and view all the current references they are not there. When I viewed my temp project after I added them they showed up fine. I attempted to just manually add the references, but nothing happened. No error, and was not added.

Another interesting thing is that when I uninstall the facebook sdk web from the NuGet interface it removes the references from the web.config, but it does not delete the files it installed. When I uninstalled the files from my temp project, all files were removed during the uninstall.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you haven't forgotten to add the Facebook.Contracts reference to your project references where you're using the library?